# Alternative of the BroadCast Receivers in Titanium appcelerator for IOS applications

Tags: ios, titanium, appcelerator

We create a Broadcast receiver in android for checking the state of wifi ,and how to check the state of wifi in Titanium for IOS applications.???
what is the alternative of broadcast receiver in Titianium for IOS application.???
I'm new in titanium  so please explain with an example...... or provide me valuable Links or understanding the concept of the Broadcast receivers in Titanium for IOS applications.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: iOS doesn't have this kind of capability

Comment: Then what's its alternative like broadcast receivers for android ???

Comment: Sorry to say that none. Android is a much more open platform than iOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Titanium docs , you can have a global event listener for detecting network changes.

Following is the code which you can use :

```
var networkIsOnline, networkType;

Ti.Network.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
networkIsOnline = e.online;
networkType = e.networkType;
});
```

Note : *networkType* value would be one of [these](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Titanium.Network-property-networkType).

So you can now check whenever the network is changing, like if it is on WIFI or 3G.